# Why 5.0/3 is 1.666667 in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, division, integer-division

I'm new in C language, but I've tried integer, float and double division in C as I'm normally doing in Java, but when I execute 5.0/3 instead of 1.6666666666666667 I'm getting 1.666667 for double division and for float division.

I had tried to execute the program using Visual Studio as I always do but I got the message "First number is 1, second one is 1.666667 and the last one is 1.666667." after executing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int firstNumber = 5 / 3;
    float secondNumber = 5.0f / 3.0f;
    double thirdNumber = 5.0 / 3.0;

    printf("First number is %d, second one is %f and the last one is %lf.", firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Why I'm getting the same result for 'secondNumber' and for 'thirdNumber'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Ppl, this question has nothing to do with marked "dupe", the question is legit and seems original.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typical [`float`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) can represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different values.

Typical [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) can represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different values.

In both types, <sup>5</sup>/<sub>3</sub>, the exact quotient of the division, is not in that set.  Instead a nearby value (some binary fraction) is used.

```
float secondNumber = 5.0f / 3.0f; // 1.66666662693023681640625
double thirdNumber = 5.0 / 3.0;   // 1.6666666666666667406815349750104360282421112060546875
```

When using `"%f"`, 6 places past the decimal point are used.  The printed text is a rounded one.  In both cases, rounding to the same.

```
1.666667
```

To see more digits, use `"%.10f"`, `"%.20f"`, etc. [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56909663/why-5-0-3-is-1-666667-in-c/56909794#comment100363743_56909663)

```
printf("%.10f\n", secondNumber);
printf("%.10f\n", thirdNumber);
```

Output

```
1.6666666269
1.6666666667
```